# jquery not working after webpage calls itself

Tags: jquery, mobile

Kind of hard to explain. But with the website here:

http://beerportfolio.com/mobile/

the button on the top left opens up the side bar navigation.

When a user puts in the login information the page calls itself with this code:

```
<h5>Sign In</h5>

 <form name=\"input\" action=\"index.php\" method=\"post\">
 User Name: <input type=\"text\" name=\"user\"  id=\"user\" />
 </p>
 Password: <input type=\"password\" name=\"password\" id=\"password\" />
 <div class=\"blank-divider\"></div>    
    <p>
 <input type=\"submit\" name = \"login\" value=\"login\" />
 </p>
 </form>
```

when the page calls itself either for a successful login or a failed login the slide out does not open anymore.

Here is the code for the jquery:

```
<!--Toggle Menu-->
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('#navigation').click(function() {
                    $('.navigation').slideToggle('fast');
                    return false;
                });
            });
</script>
```

To summarize how to reproduce the problem go to the above link. Try the button in the top right to see the side bar pop in and out. Then enter in some random login info and try to login. When the next page loads try the login button in the top left again and now the side bar will not come out.

Any ideas whats going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research I find that this has to do with the page refreshes being done with ajax automatically in jquery mobile.

A quick fix for me was this:

```
data-ajax="false"
```

using that above attribute in the form element forces a full page refresh thus allowing my query call to work.

This is not the ideal fix, as I am still trying to figure this one out. But this is a quick and dirty fix for now.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I noted, there is no element with a 'navigation' ID when the page is loaded. If it's being added dynamically, it won't work unless you use .on to bind it to the body.

I changed $('#navigation') for $('.showMenu') and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I changed it to this:

http://pastebin.com/VsKsEaGe

and it didnt change anything for me.

Did I change the wrong thing?

Comment: You changed the right thing in pastebin but I just entered your site and the wrong code continue there.

Comment: try reloading it, i put it back for other people reading the post but now Its live with your correction

Comment: I put two different solutions here: http://jsfiddle.net/v5chK/

The first is better but I'm not sure if it works with the version of Jquery you're using. If it doesn't work, try the second.

If neither work, just let me know and we try something else.

Comment: Neither work, I left the second one up so you can test on the live site for yourself.

Comment: I'm not used with jquery mobile but, if you can listen to the event thrown when the page changes (and you probably can), you can probably rebind the click action.

Comment: I didnt think this jquery "mobile" I thought i twas all one. Its odd that it works perfectly before the website calls itself again...

Comment: I took a look at the mobile docs and the first thing is : "Important: Use $(document).bind('pageinit'), not $(document).ready()".
I think you issue might be related...
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html

Comment: Thanks, just read into that and played with it. Still didnt work, thanks for the try though.